# How to send multiple transactions simultaneously from the wallet?

Tags: transaction, wallet, private-key

- **Case 1** : I have IOTAs on 1 address

  User can't send to multiple addresses simultaneously. ***Private key reuse.***
- **Case 2**: I have IOTAs on multiple addresses

  User can't choose the address to spend on GUI wallet.

  Is it possible via API for case 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the current wallet don't support this kind of *complex* scenario (i.e. sending to multiple addresses simultaneously). You have to craft a proper Bundle to send funds to multiple addresses.

**Case 1** :

- Assume that you have 600 iotas in <MY_ADDRESS>
- Assume that you need to send 200 iotas to Alice
- Assume that you need to send 300 iotas to Bob

You need to craft a Bundle with the following transactions in it :

```
<MY_ADDRESS> send 200 to <ALICE_ADDRESS>
<MY_ADDRESS> send 300 to <BOB_ADDRESS>
<MY_ADDRESS> send 100 to <MY_OTHER_ADDRESS>
```

You need to sign all those transaction with the private key of <MY_ADDRESS>

**Case 2** :

- Assume that you have 300 iotas in <MY_ADDRESS_1>
- Assume that you have 300 iotas in <MY_ADDRESS_2>
- Assume that you need to send 200 iotas to Alice
- Assume that you need to send 300 iotas to Bob

You need to craft a Bundle with the following transactions in it :

```
<MY_ADDRESS_1> send 200 to <ALICE_ADDRESS>
<MY_ADDRESS_1> send 100 to <BOB_ADDRESS>
<MY_ADDRESS_2> send 200 to <BOB_ADDRESS>
<MY_ADDRESS_2> send 100 to <MY_OTHER_ADDRESS>
```

Of course the first transactions must be signed with the private key for <MY_ADDRESS_1> and the 2 last transactions must be signed with private key for <MY_ADDRESS_2>

More info about bundles :

- https://domschiener.gitbooks.io/iota-guide/content/chapter1/bundles.html
- [What is an input transaction, and what does its "address" field represent?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/389/what-is-an-input-transaction-and-what-does-its-address-field-represent)

Comment: In your last example, 100 iotas are left on `<MY_ADDRESS_1>` and you overspend 100 iotas on `<MY_ADDRESS_2>`. Are those transactions still considered valid ?

Comment: @aguadoe : good catch. I fixed it.